# Is "Last X. I spent it" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Example sentence (from my own writing):

> **Last week, I spent it sending letters,** pretending to be someone else.

The the bolded part grammatical? Why or why not?

If it's not grammatical, what's the correct alternative?

Comment: If the preceding sentence is: _"Wednesday is the day when I do nothing but write"_, your sentence would not be out of place in a work of fiction. It is perfectly grammatical in any case. Without knowing more about the context in which it appears, there is absolutely nothing more that can be said about it with any confidence.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to tell us the context in which this sentence appears. Is it something you wrote? Did you find it somewhere? Without more information, we can only guess at its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is not precisely ungrammatical, the *it* would typically refer to something other than *last week*. The normal construction is this:

> I spent last week sending letters, pretending to be someone else.

Now, have a look at this:

> I get a small amount of time to myself each week. Last week, I spent it sending letters, pretending to be someone else.

In this case, the *it* refers to the small amount of time. Your sentence is the normal means of expressing this.

Now, in a conversation, you might say *last week*, then pause for thought, and then say *I spent it sending letters.* In that case, you might write it like this:

> Last week...I spent it sending letters, pretending to be someone else.

Otherwise, you would typically introduce *last week* in some way:

> As for last week, I spent it sending letters.

This would imply one item in an explanation of how you had spent a period of time.